# Angular material2 sidenav not showing despite being in the dom

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an issue where the sidenav and header are different components sharing a service. This appears to be working when inspecting the sidenav element i can see the toggling to open and close. The problem i am having with this is no sidenav actually appears.

[image: md-sidenav not appearing visually, although it is in the DOM]

**component file**:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';

import { SidenavToggleService } from './shared/sidenavToggle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.css']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MdSidenav;

  /**
   * Constructor of the class.
   * @param {sidenavService} SidenavToggleService
   */
  constructor(public sidenavService: SidenavToggleService) {}

  /**
   * OnInit life cycle hook
   */
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
  }

}
```

**html file**:

```html
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over">
testerer
  </md-sidenav>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

**service file**:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MdSidenav, MdSidenavToggleResult } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavToggleService {
  private sidenav: MdSidenav;

  /**
   * Setter for sidenav.
   *
   * @param {MdSidenav} sidenav
   */
  public setSidenav(sidenav: MdSidenav) {
    this.sidenav = sidenav;
  }

  /**
   * Open this sidenav, and return a Promise that will resolve when it's fully opened (or get rejected if it didn't).
   *
   * @returns Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult>
   */
  public open(): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.open();
  }

  /**
   * Close this sidenav, and return a Promise that will resolve when it's fully closed (or get rejected if it didn't).
   *
   * @returns Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult>
   */
  public close(): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.close();
  }

  /**
   * Toggle this sidenav. This is equivalent to calling open() when it's already opened, or close() when it's closed.
   *
   * @param {boolean} isOpen  Whether the sidenav should be open.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult>}
   */
  public toggle(isOpen?: boolean): Promise<MdSidenavToggleResult> {
    console.log('uh');
    return this.sidenav.toggle(isOpen);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Added the service I am using

Comment: What if you give it a height?

Comment: You should do this in ngAfterViewInit also: **this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);**

Comment: Height doesnt change anything and i corrected the sidenav assigment to afterviewinit still doesnt work but i agree it should be in the afterview creation. No errors in console and the service function is being called (i can see my console log message).

Answer (score 4):

Please set fixedInViewport in sidenav, will fixed the issue

`<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" [fixedInViewport]="true" >
  <!-- content -->
</md-sidenav>`

Comment: This is not a valid answer if I don't want it to be fixed in viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I had to wrap the toolbar component in sidenav-container......

```js
<div >
  <md-sidenav-container>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
  </md-sidenav-container>
  test
</div>
```

why i have to do that i have no idea but it works now. I have to now work on position etc.

Comment: I have a mat-sidenav-contanier as its parent but it doesn't work